# Truncation of floating point numbers

Tags: python, truncation

I would like to truncate a floating point number at the third decimal place. However, I don't want to round the number.

```py
float("{0:.3f}".format(132.32579))
```

The code above produces 132.326 but I want it to produce 132.325. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can round to 1 digit more, slice the string for ignoring the last digit and convert back to float:

```
print( float("{0:.4f}".format(132.32579) [:-1]))
```

You can avoid the string conversion/rounding by multiplying by 1000, converting to int and dividing by 1000.0 again:

```
print( float(int(132.32579*1000)/1000.0))
```

Output (both):

```
132.325
```